# Is clone method expensive in terms of performance compared with Spring provided BeanUtils.copyProperties?

Tags: java, performance, spring

Please provide more details or alternative approaches for this.

Please note: I am not overriding the clone method, also I will be grateful if anybody could explain if I should override the clone method and what the advantage would be.

Comment: Without overriding clone method a class can't be cloned.If the depth of composition is more then it create complex scenario where cloning will affect the performance.However Overriding the Object Clone method it will provide cloning instances.

Comment: I am not overrideing the clone method, i just create a util method like this public static <T> T clone(Class<T> clazz, T dtls) {
        T clonedObject = (T) SerializationHelper.clone((Serializable) dtls);
        return clonedObject;
    }, when I am checking performance using profileing option, seems this method is takeing a long time as well memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about performance, clone performance is OK. But you can clone only Cloneable objects, while Spring's BeanUtils.copyProperties can copy properties of any JavaBean object (public no-args constructor and setter / getters for properties). E.g. this works fine copying properties of 2  objects of different classes

```
class X {
    String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Y {
    String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        X x = new X();
        x.setName("test");
        Y y = new Y();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(x, y);
        System.out.println(y.getName());
    }
}
```

and prints

```
test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this description....in my code I am creating a util method like public static <T> T clone(Class<T> clazz, T dtls) {
        T clonedObject = (T) SerializationHelper.clone((Serializable) dtls);
        return clonedObject;
    } when i checking in profileing mode(JVM monitor), its shows a huge memory consumption as well time taking.....So any suggection for this.

Comment: With serialization, you are doing a "deep" copy of the object.  This means that if you copy an object that has references to other objects (which could again have references to more objects), the "nested" objects will be copied as well. With BeanUtils, only the object _reference_ would be copied.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use a copy constructor instead?

```java
public class User {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    // 0-arg constructor
    public User() {        
    }

    // classic constructor
    public User(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    // copy constructor
    public User(User copy) {
        firstname = copy.getFirstname();
        lastname = copy.getLastname();
    }

    // accessors omitted

}
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```java
User johnDoe = new User("john", "doe");
User copy = new User(johnDoe);
```

It's a quite common way to do, and the advantage is that you manually decide what properties you copy or not, and how you copy them.

Comment: what will be the difference between constructor approach and beanutils.copyproperties approach? which will be faster?